# Hotine Oblique Mercator projection Where is the code in C/C++/Python?

Tags: gdal, proj, osgeo, mercator

For these functions:

SetHOM()
Set a Hotine Oblique Mercator projection using azimuth angle.

SetHOM2PNO()
Set a Hotine Oblique Mercator projection using two points on projection centerline.

SetHOMAC()
Set an Hotine Oblique Mercator azimuth center projection using azimuth angle.

https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRSpatialReference.html#a66530428642a5e5e16f7791c7474fd21

What computational code is behind these functions ( C / C++ / Python ) ? Is it in the GDAL, OSGEO or PROJ library ?

Comment: [SetHOM()](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrspatialreference.cpp#L6693), [SetHOM2PNO](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrspatialreference.cpp#L6750), and [SetHOMAC()](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrspatialreference.cpp#L6633) all call proj functions, so start there I'd say, e.g. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AOSGeo%2FPROJ%20proj_create_conversion_hotine_oblique_mercator_variant_a&type=code

Comment: the calculation code is quite complicated and must include calculations similar to this type:

http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/hotine_oblique_mercator.html

in the provided references there are only definitions and not the calculation code

Comment: You'll need to look through the PROJ code. The refererence I provided is just a starting point.